# Check multiple checkboxes with the same id

Tags: html, angularjs, materialize

I made a todo app in HTML with AngularJS and I am using materializecss for the design. I create a todo task and it works, materialize needs a id for the input and a label tag. I created a ID for the new todos but the problem is that when I click on a checkbox it selects the first one. Can anyone help me find a solution to that ? The code is on this webpage : http://touficapks.ml/ToDo_app. Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you are using an id rather than a class in this case?

Comment: You should never re-use ID's in HTML. Classes should be used instead.

Comment: @JasonAller Yes, materializecss uses the id

Comment: @TylerRoper I know, materializecss is the problem

Comment: @TouficBatache There *has* to be a way to use either unique IDs for repeating elements, or classes, in materializecss. Unfortunately I'm not posting an answer because I'm unfamiliar.

Comment: @TylerRoper Thanks for your help but Thomas answered below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `id="todo-{{$index}}"` within the `ng-repeat`.

Comment: @TouficBatache you may consider checking this as the correct answer since it worked for you

Comment: @Mi-Creativity I have to wait 7 minutes ;)

Comment: Ok then I apologize :)

Comment: @Mi-Creativity No problem!